# HOw to view all Logs in OSSSEC system ubuntu

Tags: linux, security, rootkit, ossec

I have installed  [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/doc/index.html)

It is working and sometime sending me alert email as well.

But i want to see what can i type so that i can get view all the logs of what OSSEC has found in my system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed ossec in it's default location then the logs are in `/var/ossec/logs`